# Spring REST Docs - how to configure asciidoctor task to include generated snippet into index?

Tags: junit5, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I'm having an `index.adoc` file located in:
`src/docs/asciidoc/index.adoc`

With contents: `include::{snippets}/add-measurement/curl-request.adoc[]`

When I call build task then generated snippets are here: `build/generated-snippets/my-call/*.adoc`

But when I look into generated `index.html` it turns out that snippets are not included:

`Unresolved directive in index.adoc - include::{snippets}/add-measurement/curl-request.adoc[]`

My `asciidoctor` task in `build.gradle`:

```
asciidoctor {
    dependsOn junitPlatformTest
}
```

When I add `sourceDir snippetsDir` to `asciidoctor` gradle task then every snippet is converted to html but `index.html` is not generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your information, `snippetsDir` is configured and snippets are placed in the expected folder and the AsciiDoctor `sourceDir` is already correct as an index.html is generated (but with broken includes). So the one thing that seems to be missing is to pass on the `snippetDir` to AsciiDoctor:

```
asciidoctor {
  inputs.dir snippetsDir
  dependsOn junitPlatformTest  
}
```

or

```
asciidoctor {
  attributes "snippets": snippetsDir
  dependsOn junitPlatformTest  
}
```

Examples for working Gradle setups:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/master/samples/rest-notes-spring-hateoas/build.gradle#L55
- https://github.com/ScaCap/spring-auto-restdocs/blob/master/spring-auto-restdocs-example/build.gradle#L80

Comment: The `snippets` attribute should be set automatically if you're using the `spring-restdocs-asciidoctor` module which provides an Asciidoctor extension. Unfortunately, there's a [bug](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/issues/222) in version 1.5.6 of the Asciidoctor Gradle plugin that means it doesn't work reliably when also using Gradle's daemon. Dropping back to 1.5.3 or disabling the daemon will fix the problem.